# How can I make this Layout Background Completely Black in color?

Tags: xml, android-layout

[Image here,Please Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgnXU.png)

> Here is my XML code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_relatives"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:id="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> I tried adding the background method to #000000
>
> but only the image background gets black color. How can i make the
>   complete white space black
>   Please reply with your valuable Suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with below xml code :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_relatives"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/custom_relatives"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of fixes you should make in your implementation.

1. RelativeLayout doesn't need you to set `android:orientation`. That's for LinearLayout.
2. You don't have any View with id *slider* and yet you have `android:layout_below="@+id/slider"`. What were you trying to do there?
3. You should be using `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`. [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) is our recommendation going forward. If you are using Android Studio, the IDE can do it for you. Just do `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX`. Otherwise you can do it yourself by adding the following to Gradle: `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'`
4. You should set the background to the topmost layout; in your case, the RelativeLayout with id `android:id="@+id/activity_main"`
5. do not hard code your colors in the layout file. Put them in `colors.xml` instead. E.g. move `#000000` to the `colors.xml` file.

So maybe in the end your layout will look as below. I also see that you are setting `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`. Is that intentional?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_relatives"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/one_dollar"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:id="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_bottom_teacher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_bottom"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```